# Reading a SAS dataset with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, dataset, sas

I'd like to be able to read a SAS dataset with Ruby.  Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to a local instance of SAS or to a SAS/SHARE server, you can use the SAS ODBC driver to connect to and read from SAS data libraries.  I run a SAS/SHARE server myself and access it from Excel all the time.

See the [SAS ODBC Driver User Manual](http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/odbc/index.html) for the version of SAS you are using for more info.

Answer (score 0):

SAS dataset files are coded in a proprietary format. If you have access to SAS, you can export the dataset as a delimited text file, and then read that with Ruby. If you don't have access to SAS, you could look into getting [StatTransfer](http://www.stattransfer.com/), but it's not cheap.

Comment: I do have access to SAS, but I was hoping to avoid the intermediate step of converting to a text file first.

Comment: You might be able to read a SAS XPORT file in Ruby, but I doubt you could read it directly otherwise.  I suppose it's possible if you have access to SAS to instruct windows to do the work for you, or otherwise use a SAS utility; R does have a method that utilizes SAS to do the work for it, for example - perhaps look at that?

Comment: Reading in an XPORT file instead of a dataset would be accecptable.  Why do you think the XPORT would be easier than the dataset?

Comment: The SAS xport file format is published, as opposed to the proprietary SAS format. See: http://support.sas.com/techsup/technote/ts140.html . The R program `read.xport` can read xport files directly, and the source of this is available: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/foreign/html/read.xport.html

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do what you want.

1. You could use the ruby gem [Pandas.rb](https://github.com/mrkn/pandas.rb) to

```
# Untested
require 'pandas'
df = Pandas.read_sas("./path/to/dataset.sas7bdat")
```

2. Alternatively, with some development effort you could implement the logic in Pandas [sas7bdat.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.24.2/pandas/io/sas/sas7bdat.py) and [xport.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.24.2/pandas/io/sas/sas_xport.py)